# Implement a Web based Client that interacts with a TCP Server

Tags: python, web-applications

**EDIT:Question Updated. Thanks Slott.**

I have a TCP Server in Python.

It is a server with asynchronous behaviour. .

The message format is Binary Data.

Currently I have a python client that interacts with the code.

What I want to be able to do eventually implement a Web based Front End to this client.

I just wanted to know , what should be correct design for such an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with any WSGI-based web server.  [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) is a choice.

The Asynchronous TCP/IP is a seriously complicated problem.  HTTP is synchronous.  So using the synchronous web server presenting some asynchronous data is always a problem.  Always.

The best you can do is to buffer things and have two processes in your web application.

1. TCP/IP process that collects data from the remove server and buffers it in a file (or files) somewhere.
2. WSGI web process which handles GET/POST processing.

   - GET requests will fetch some or all of the buffer and display it.
   - POST requests will send a message to the TCP/IP server.

Comment: Exactly thats what I am thinking, using TCP/IP and returning the results for display but there are also some asynchronous elements to this application. I was wondering How would I implement this on the client side, as in Javascript<->python interactions

Comment: something like a python server calling JavaScript Asynchronously.

Comment: @anijhaw: **Update** your question to contain **all** the relevant information.  Your question says "simple server with a request-reply behavior".  Your comment says "some asynchronous elements".  Please pick one of the two and stick to it.  Please don't randomly add new requirements.  Please don't add requirements in a comment.  Please **update** your question to be complete and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

For Web-based, talk HTTP. Use [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or XML as data formats.

Be standards-compliant and make use of the vast number of libraries out there. Don't reinvent the wheel. This way you have less headaches in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to maintain a connection to a backend server across multiple HTTP requests, [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com)'s HTTP server is an ideal choice, since it's built to manage multiple connections easily.